# Why is my very simple makefile not working

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

When I say very simple I mean it. I have a main.c and a header file called input_error.h.

```
main.o : main.c input_error.h
    gcc -c main.c
```

When I run the command "make" gcc -c main.c is executed but it's not updating any changes I make to my main.c file. When I manually type in "gcc main.c" it works fine.

EDIT: It seems like I need to add another rule but I'm not sure what that entails

Comment: `gcc -c main.c is executed but it's not updating any change`. That's impossible. If the comand runs then it will produce the latest `.o` file from the `.c` file at that time. So you are mis-interpreting something. Please be more clear in how you think it is "not updating any change". If you mean it does not produce the final executable then that's because that rule only builds the intermediate object and does not link. If you have a seperate linking rule then please show it.

Comment: Note that running `gcc main.c` manually is not the same as the rule command `gcc -c main.c` in the makefile. So it is not comparable.

Comment: Yes this is the complete makefile. If I go into main.c and add 'printf("Hello World\n' then run make. It doesn't show up

Comment: That's because you don't have any rule to produce the final executable. `main.o` is not the final executable.

Comment: The final target for this makefile is `main.o`. If you are expecting an executable called `main` the makefile needs to either add another rule or build the binary in one step.

Comment: How do I link the executable?

Answer (score 3):

At the moment your makefile only builds the .o file. You can build your binary in 2 ways. Note that make requires the indentation in the targets statements to be a tab and not 4 spaces, as it may have been converted to by the browser.

build `.o` separately then link binary. Note that using the `-c` switch causes gcc to build only the object file.

```
main: main.o
    gcc main.o -o main

main.o : main.c input_error.h
    gcc -c main.c -o main.o
```

build in one step

```
main: main.c input_error.h
    gcc main.c -o main
```

You can also avoid repetition in your makefile by using special variables to denote the target ($@), the first dependency ($<) and all (@^) the dependencies.

e.g. one of the above lines could become

```
main.o : main.c input_error.h
        gcc -c $< -o $@
```

Which seems a bit cryptic at first but you get used it. The implicit rules in @kaylums answer will also help to cut down on typing.

Comment: I really appreciate the fast answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Makefile you have only has a single rule to compile the `.o` file. That is, it does not have any rule to link the final executable.

`make` has implicit rules for building many common targets. So your Makefile could be as simple as the following:

```
all: main

main.o : input_error.h
```

For further explanation:

- `all: main`: Since this is the first target it is the one that will be built by default if no explicit target is provided to the `make` command line. It depends on a single target `main`.
- There is no explicit rule for `main` but `make` has an implicit rule which will build it from `main.c`.
- `main.o : input_error.h`: Tells `make` that `main.o` needs to be rebuilt if `input_error.h` changes. There is no need to put `main.c` here as `make` has that implicit knowledge. There is also no need for an explicit command as `make` also has that implicit.